# Optimising simple methods

Tags: java, methods, repeat

So basically I have an example here where I am creating two methods, one that returns the full price from a class which contains the price of the unit  and another method which returns the price post discount.

```
public int getFullPrice(Product product){
        int pricePerUnit = product.getPricePerUnit();
        int fullPrice = this.quantity * pricePerUnit;
        return fullPrice;
    }
    public int priceAfterDiscount(Product product){
        int pricePerUnit = product.getPricePerUnit();
        int fullPrice = this.quantity * pricePerUnit;
        return fullPrice - this.discountRate;
    }
```

I was wondering whether it would be better practice to create variables inside the first method that could be passed onto the second method, or whether this is bad practice because although I may be reusing code if the second method has been executed it would have to go through the first method before right?

```
public int getFullPrice(Product product){
        int pricePerUnit = product.getPricePerUnit();
        int fullPrice = this.quantity * pricePerUnit;
        return fullPrice;
    }
    public int priceAfterDiscount(int fullPrice){
        return fullPrice - this.discountRate;
    }
```

I'm not 100% sure whether its taking the fullPrice from the first method. Or whether the approach I'm taking is irrational. I know there's bound to be a much simplier way of doing this without repeating code

Comment: Wouldn't these methods be part of the Product class? If so, then you would not want to give it a Product parameter since it will use the state of the current instance, the `this`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code behaviour that relies on side effects, particularly side effects of previously executed code is almost always a bad idea.

If there is common code shared between two public methods the better approach is to refactor the common code into a private or protected method.

In this case your price after discount is performing precisely the same calculation of the full price calculation, so call it first then post process to reduce the duplicated code. (if I understood):

```
public int getFullPrice(Product product){
    int pricePerUnit = product.getPricePerUnit();
    int fullPrice = this.quantity * pricePerUnit;
    return fullPrice;
}

public int priceAfterDiscount(Product product){
    return getFullPrice(product) - this.discountRate;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this instead?

```
public int getFullPrice(Product product){
    int pricePerUnit = product.getPricePerUnit();
    return this.quantity * pricePerUnit;
}

public int priceAfterDiscount(Product product){
    return getFullPrice(product) - this.discountRate;
}
```

Comment: It seems logical, I'm just never sure how to tell what is most efficient

Comment: @SmallLegend efficiency is the last thing you should worry about. Think about correctness, readability and maintainability. In your above example, the caller of the methods need to call 2 methods, in the right order, to get the discount price. Why force him to do that instead of providing a single method doing it for him? You would have to call these methods millions of time to start seeing a difference, if any.